# What's the use of the word 's in this sentence

Tags: usage, possessives

Could you explain how the apostrophe 's works in these sentences? I understand the word 's to show possesive meaning to belong. But it doesn't make sense in this case.

> "A huge victory for Everton"
> **Sky Sports' Jamie Carragher:** "It feels like a huge victory for them. It gives them a little bit of breathing space between themselves and the bottom three."

> **Manchester City's Erling Haaland.**
> **Pep Guardiola's Manchester City**.

In these sentences, if the word 's means to belong, the sentences go something like this:

Sky Sports's Jamie Carragher  means Jamie Carragher is the owner of Sky Sports.
Manchester City's Erling Haaland means Enrling Haaland is the owner of Manchester City.
Pep Guardiola's Mancherster City means Mancherster is the owner of Pep Guadiola.

Comment: The apostrophe s (possessive) does not mean ownership in English. Compare Joe's teacher, Joe's student, Joe's football club, Joe's friend, Joe's country.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I understand your examples. But when the apostrophe 's is related to sports, it sounds somewhat awkward to me. Sky Sports' Jamie Carragher would mean Jamie Carragher belongs to Sky Sports. In other words, he's the owner of Sky Sports. Manchester City's Erling Haaland = Erling Haalnd is the owner Manchester City.  Pep Guardiola's Manchester City = Pep is the owner of Mancherster City. This doesn't make any sense because Erling Haaland is a player for Man City and Pep is a manager/coach for Man City, while Jamie Carragher might be a pundit on Sky Sports?

Comment: "Sky Sports' Jamie Carragher" may refer to a commentator or journalist, or it may refer to a person who can speak on behalf of the organisation. If he was saying Fred was changing clubs the former would be more likely; if he was announcing a deal to for Sky Sports to broadcast the World Cup, then the latter would be more likely. (I don't actually know which is true, but it doesn't affect the understanding).

Comment: @Peter Yes, he is a commentator or journalist. You mean the apostrophe 's  mean to speak, don't you? Sky Sports' Jamie Caragher = Jamie Carragher speaks on Sky Sports. Is my understanding right?

Comment: For this specific example it means he is part of the Sky Sports organisation.

Comment: If you think of 's as similar to "of", which also has lots of meanings (which overlap but don't entirely match - sometimes 's is better replaced by "from" or "in" etc).

Comment: 's isn't a word and we don't think of it as one. It's a suffix or clitic.

Comment: @StuartF You're right the 's can be replaced by "of", but not for "from" or "in" in this sense. It would have a different meaning, I think.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned a key matter, that we can place the possessive apostrophe (by itself) after a word that already ends with the letter 's'. So _Sky Sports' Jamie Carragher_ is someone who belongs to (works for) Sky Sports (the name of the organisation), and we write _Manchester City's_ with an apostrophe and then an 's' because 'City' does not end with an 's'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is there any difference between Man City's Pep Guardiola" and Pep Guardiola's Man City?"

Comment: @Nyambek - Yes. The first is the manager, and the second is the team.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't understand the second. Do you mean Manchester City belong to Pep Guardiola? Manchester City work for Pep Guardiola.

Comment: @Nyambek (1) Man City's Pep Guardiola - The team has (possesses) a manager whose name is PG - focus on the person.  (2) Pep Guardiola's Man City - PG's team (the team during his management period) which is different from Manuel Pellegrini's Man City, and very different from Les McDowall's Man City - focus on the team.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. That's very clear. What about the sentence "Man City's Erling Haaland?" Man City has a player whose name is Erling Haaland?

Comment: @Nyambek - you have understood!

Answer (score 2):

The 's indicates possession in a very general sense, not specifically ownership. It represents the relationship "A has B".

You could say that Sky Sports has Jamie Carragher as a journalist.  Or that Pep Guardiola has Manchester City, as the club he manages.

*Compare Joe's teacher, Joe's student, Joe's football club, Joe's friend, Joe's country. (-Peter)*

Now in both these examples I was able to insert "as ..." which I infered from context and general knowledge.  It would also be possible to talk about "Manchester City's Pep Guardiola"  (City has Pep as a manager) Possession can run both ways.

There is no mistake here, but perhaps these examples would be expressed differently if there had been more space.  The examples from newspapers are kept short. It is common to talk about "Joe's teacher", but if that teacher was named Jill, it would not be common to talk about "Joe's Jill", because the relationship "as a teacher" can't be infered.

Comment: Interesting. As for "Manchester City's Pep and Pep's Manchester City, Do they both mean the same thing? I would interpret "Man City's Pep" as meaning "Pep is a player, not a manager and Pep's Man City belongs to Man City, in other words he is the manager for Man City in the same way as Man City's Erling Haalnd is Erling Haaland is a player for Man City. What do you think?

Comment: "Manchester City's Pep Guardiola" means that he is associated with the club in some way; it does **not** imply anything about what that association is.

Comment: And your confusion illustrates perfectly why contemporary grammarians do not use the term *possessive* for such ‘s constructions. Instead, they use the more general term *genitive*. In “Mark’s valor is impressive,” one wouldn’t say that Mark \**owns* the valor or that he \**possesses* it, but instead something like he *displays* it.

Comment: @paul  But "genitive" is wrong for the 's clitic.  Since genitive is a case, and English doesn't have cases (except for pronouns).

Comment: @JamesK, don’t shoot the messenger.  It’s also sometimes called the Saxon genitive.